# Undefined class Route (Laravel in PhpStorm)

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, phpstorm, laravel-facade

How can I fix this alert in PhpStorm?

[image]

And also how to get autocompletion for Route and other Facades?

Comment: 1) http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/01/laravel-development-using-phpstorm/ 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm

Comment: Thank you. That is what I need.

Answer (score 74):

Check the [Laracasts walkthrough](https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/15)

1) Go to: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

2) Click on the gist

Generated version for L5: https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822

3) Click on "Raw" to get the current version (as of June 22, 2016 it is):

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/barryvdh/5227822/raw/4d4b0ca26055fa4753b38edeb94fad2396c497c0/_ide_helper.php

4) Make sure you're in your root directory (this is mine)

```
cd /var/www/html/project
```

5) Download the gist:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/barryvdh/5227822/raw/4d4b0ca26055fa4753b38edeb94fad2396c497c0/_ide_helper.php
```

6) Add "_ide_helper.php" to the `.gitignore` file

```
sudo nano .gitignore
```

Add "_ide_helper.php" on a new line at the bottom

7) Download the `.gitignore` and `_ide_helper.php` files into PhpStorm

This is what my PhpStorm project directory looks like afterwards:

[image]

8) After the files are downloaded into PhpStorm, the "Undefined class" error will disappear and autocompletion will now work. Might need to restart it.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, just as @Bxx explains.

Comment: To make this answer a bit more concise:
Download the _ide_helper.php for your version of laravel from https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper and save the file in the project folder of your PHPStorm/IntelliJ project.

Comment: Or you could simply, you know, follow instructions there and it's even simpler! `composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` and then `php artisan ide-helper:generate` - done

Answer (score 31):

There is greate IDE support for Laravel shipped from Baryvdh:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

after you install it you just call in the console:

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

which generate alll facede shortcuts in `_ide_helper.php` file (which you have to exclude from git)

There is also something special for PhpStorm:

```
php artisan ide-helper:meta
```

which will give Laravel container context for example:

```
$foo = app(Foo::class);
```

PhpStorm will know that the `$foo` variable is type of `Foo` class.

Answer (score 25):

I know this is an old thread, but it is still relevant. For me, I decided to add the following to my `routes/web.php` since I don't want to have to worry about regenerating meta data for the app.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

**Edit:** The above does not add any overhead to PHP as the `use` simply acts as a reference for PHP.

Comment: Easy and effective solution that does not require installing extra modules.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem simply by installing the Laravel idea plugin.
Use the following link:
https://laravel-idea.com/
You can install it on your phpstorm.
Its good feature is that you can use it for 30 days for free and pay the amount after satisfaction.