# Undefined Class App in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

This is so basic, but driving me mad. In the laracast video https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/24, right at the start, Jeffery types

```
App::bind(.....
```

into web.php.

I have a new install of Laravel 5.4. If I type 
    App::bind

I get "undefined class App". If I give a full path name

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::bind
```

it says method bind not found in \Illuminate\Support\Facades.

What am I doing wrong. I thought Facades were all registered automatically.

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. PHPStorm is telling me that the facade doesn't exist. I need to install an IDE-Helper as PHPStorm can't resolve facades. Finished the code example and it does actually work, just need to ignore all the PHPStorm coding errors.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419143/undefined-class-route-laravel-in-phpstorm

Comment: You need to add the Laravel IDE helper as a `ServiceProvider` into your application. In the `app/config/app.php file`, add `'Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider'` under the `providers` element and then run the `artisan ide-helper:generate` command! This will fixed your issue!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`app()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-app) helper instead of `App::bind()` facade or use full namespace which is `\App::bind()`.

Also, you really shouldn't do that in `web.php`, use service providers instead.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container

Comment: Jeffery only types App::bind. Why do I need to enter \App::bind or use a helper function ? I know about not doing it in web.php, only following his video demo. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the full `App` namespace. You need to use `\App::bind` since `App` is a facade

Comment: Jeffery only types App::bind. Why do I need to enter \App::bind ?

Comment: Is `'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,` in the `aliases` array in `config/app.php`?

Comment: Yep, aliases array includes App. As I said, this is a fresh install. Nothing done to it. It's very strange.

Comment: Try and see if `composer dumpautoload` fixes it